# How to find the reason of the alert sound?

Tags: gnome, sound, notification

I am getting alert sounds at random times and even when I am not using the computer. I wanted to ask here before disabling the alert sound. Are there any logs so that I can see what causes those alert sounds?

I am on Ubuntu Gnome 17.04. 
Thanks.

Comment: Have you clicked on the date/time in the top panel to check for notifications?

Comment: Yes, it is not in the notification list. It is an alert (default "drip") sound and I don't think it generates any notification. It is the sound you get when you press tab and autocomplete fails in the terminal.

Comment: You might leave the Sound panel open in the Applications tab to see if you can catch which app is doing it.

Answer (score -1):

There is a tool called "Recent Notifications" that may help

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jconti/recent-notifications
sudo apt update && sudo apt install indicator-notifications
```

Log out/log back in and in your top right of the screen you should have a mailbox icon. You can customize the settings as well, but as that is outside of the scope of your question you could simply google how to make changes, blacklist apps, etc.

Hope it helps!